# jQuery removing mCsutomScrollbar from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Using [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) on jQuery UI dialogs.

If I initiate mCsutomScrollbar on $(window).load as proposed on the mCsutomScrollbar instructions, it does not work because my dialogs are not visible at that point. So I have to initiate mCsutomScrollbar on the open event of the dialog.

```
open: function() {
    $(this).mCustomScrollbar();
    }
```

Which works except when I open the same dialog a second time mCustomScrollbar is initialized for a second time when it already is initialized and breaks. I can see the custom scrollbar but I cannot scroll.

So it seems I need a way to remove mCustomScrollbar on close or beforeclose event of the dialog. Not exactly sure how to do this.

Comment: Try initialize the mCustomScrollbar after $('.dialog').dialog();

Comment: .dialog is called in a .click function so does not really work is this situation, still need a way to remove mCustomScrollbar

Comment: You can try use a update method of mCustomScrollbar() in onclick

Comment: FYI I did try initializing mCustomScrollbar after .dialog and it only works the first time the dialog is opened just like when using the open event. Still need a way to remove mCustomScrollbar on close. I also tried initializing mCustomScrollbar in the dialog create event and it does not work at all. Seems the only point where mCustomScrollbar can be called is when the element is open and visible.

Comment: I tried .mCustomScrollbar("update"); does not seem to work either :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

turns out there is a built in function in mCustomScrollbar that does what I need

[$('selector').mCustomScrollbar("destroy")](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/disable_destroy_example.html)